# ТypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство "postData" объекта undefined

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, google-apps-script

```
function doPost(e) {
 
  // Make sure to only reply to json requests
  
  
if(e.postData.type == "application/json") {
 
  // Parse the update sent from Telegram
  var update = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
 // Instantiate our bot passing the update 
    var bot = new Bot(token, update);
    
    // Building commands
  
    var bus = new CommandBus();
    bus.on(/\/start/, function () {
      this.replyToSender("Работаем");
    });
    
    bus.on(/\/joke\s*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)?\s*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)?/, randomJoke);
    
    // Register the command bus
    bot.register(bus);
    
    // If the update is valid, process it
    if (update) {
      bot.process();
    }
```

При отладке функции dоPost вылезает ошибка:

> ТypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство "postData" объекта undefined.

Помогите, пожалуйста, устранить ошибку. Работаю с Гугл скрипт. Пытаюсь научиться написать телеграмм бота. Готовый скрипт нашел в интернете, но он не срабатывает. Опубликовывал скрипт как веб, всегда сохраняя новую версию для всех. После публикации в проверке работы скрипта гуглом, пишет:

> Не удалось найти функцию скрипта: doGet

Answer (score 0):

Если я все верно понимаю, то вы производите отладку скрипта, которому ничего не присылаете, а значит никакого типа у сообщения нет. Оберните все внутри `doPost(e)` в:

```
try{...} catch(e){
sendText(myId, JSON.stringify(e,null,4));}
```

И начните работать напрямую с вебхуком и сообщениями. Таким образом если ваш код будет работать не так, как вы бы того хотели, то вы сможете его отладить.